# How can I use angularjs promise chain in a service and controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I found this plnkr link on the web but I need use it with 2 or 3 more ajax calls which doesn't require an argument from the first ajax call. How can I do it with error handling?

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service("githubService", function($http, $q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  this.getAccount = function() {
    return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/haroldrv')
      .then(function(response) {
        // promise is fulfilled
        deferred.resolve(response.data);
        return deferred.promise;
      }, function(response) {
        // the following line rejects the promise 
        deferred.reject(response);
        return deferred.promise;
      });
  };
});

app.controller("promiseController", function($scope, $q, githubService) {

  githubService.getAccount()
    .then(
      function(result) {
        // promise was fullfilled (regardless of outcome)
        // checks for information will be peformed here
        $scope.account = result;
      },
      function(error) {
        // handle errors here
        console.log(error.statusText);
      }
    );
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/kACAcbCUIGSLRHV0qojK?p=preview

Comment: Give us more detail about `different ajax calls`

Comment: @WorkWe I mean more, not different, I have fixed the question now.

Comment: you could use `$q.all` to wait till all promise get resolved like `$q.all([promise1, promise2]).then(funtion(data){ //success })`

Comment: @PankajParkar I am very new at angular so could you show me how to write these with a plunkr example?

Comment: also this code is using an anti-pattern, `$http` returns a promise so there is no reason to wrap it inside a `deferred`.

Comment: @PankajParkar is correct and honestly a quick google for `$q.all example` gives what you need ( First result on google :  http://jsfiddle.net/jsengel/mc3p01nb/ )

Comment: Actually, what do you mean by `I need 2 or 3 more ajax calls` simultaneously, chained ? This could lead to a very different answer if what you need is the answer from the first ajax call to return an item you REQUIRE for the second call.. In which case stick to `githubService.getAccount().then(function (responseGetAccount) { return githubService.getSomeOtherStuff(responseGetAccount); }).then(function (responseGetOtherStuff) { /**/ }); ... `

Comment: @DarkUrse You are right, for now it doesn't require anything from the first ajax call actually. But I have to keep it in my mind what if I need to use an argument from first ajax call. Could you please show me how can I do this with my functions in plunkr? Thanks a lot! (I have edited the question like you said.)

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel with a plunkr. Instead read this nice article http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/ which explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$q.all`

```
var promises=[
$http.get(URL1),
$http.get(URL2),
$http.get(URL3),
$http.get(URL4)
];

$q.all(promises).then(function(response){
console.log('Response of Url1', response[0]);
console.log('Response of Url2', response[1]);
console.log('Response of Url3', response[2]);
console.log('Response of Url4', response[3]);
}, function(error){

});
```

I have forked your [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OnJglTlSesuAXJVEGKaT?p=preview) with `$q`

Answer (score 1):

First you should make `deferred` variable local for each ajax call you want to return a promise. So, you have to create 2-3 functions (as many as your ajax calls) and keep them in an array. Then you should use:

```
$q.all([ajax1,ajax2,ajax3]).then(function(values){
    console.log(values[0]); // value ajax1
    console.log(values[1]); // value ajax2
    console.log(values[2]);}); //value ajax3
```

example:

```
function ajax_N() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();

    http(...).then((response) => {
      deferred.resolve(response);
   }, (error) => {
      deferred.reject(error);
   });

   return deferred.promise;
}

$q.all([
        ajax_1,ajax_2,ajax_3
     ]).then(function(values) {        
          console.log(values); 
          return values;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$q.all` in this case. It will call `getAccount` and `getSomeThing` api same time.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.service("githubService", function($http, $q) {

  return {

    getAccount: function () {
      return $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/haroldrv');
    },

    getSomeThing: function () {
      return $http.get('some thing url');
    }
  };

});

app.controller("promiseController", function($scope, $q, githubService) {

  function initData () {
    $q.all([githubService.getAccount(), githubService.getSomeThing()])
      .then(
        function (data) {
          $scope.account = data[0];
          $scope.someThing = data[1];
        },
        function (error) {

        }
      );
  }
});
```